# Jenkins declarative pipeline - use withcredential of AWS

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

In my prev Jenkinsfile, I used to have this:

```
withCredentials([[ $class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',
                   credentialsId : 'aws',                                                 
                   accessKeyVariable: 'KEY_1',
                   secretKeyVariable: 'KEY_2'
                                     ]]) {
    node(..) { .. } }
```

e.g. all stages where I need to use AWS creds are wrapped with withCreds, however with declarative syntax, I have to use that `withCredentials` block **per stage** which is not acceptable.  I read that there is some `credentials('aws')` option in `environments {}` block, though I can't figure out how I can specify my cred class there and seems, it's wrong thing to look at.

```
pipeline {
   stages {
       stage('A') {
           steps {
              withCredentials([[ $class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',
                   credentialsId : 'aws',                                                 
                   accessKeyVariable: 'KEY_1',
                   secretKeyVariable: 'KEY_2'
                                     ]]) { .. }
           }
       }
       stage('B') {
           steps {
              withCredentials([[ $class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',
                   credentialsId : 'aws',                                                 
                   accessKeyVariable: 'KEY_1',
                   secretKeyVariable: 'KEY_2'
                                     ]]) { .. }
           }
       }
   }

}
```

Please let me know how I can wrap my several stages `withCredentials` in Jenkins declarative syntax. Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem with you, looks like the `withCredentials` can only be in `node` context in `scripted pipeline`.

Comment: I figured out a solution: you can wrap the `withCredentials` by `script`, for example, ```steps{ script { withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use the export command.

```
bindings

    Array/List
    Nested Choice of Objects
    $class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding'
    Sets one variable to the AWS access key and another one to the secret key given in the credentials.
        accessKeyVariable
        Environment variable name for the AWS Access Key Id. If empty, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID will be used.
            Type: String
        secretKeyVariable
        Environment variable name for the AWS Secret Access Key. If empty, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY will be used.
            Type: String
        credentialsId
        Credentials of an appropriate type to be set to the variable.
            Type: String
```

Just put an "export accessKeyVariable" and "export secretKeyVariable" in your code and this should be available in other stages.

Comment: I'm a bit baffled as to how this would work.  Since "export" is a shell command, how would that get run in an execution context that is the same as the withCredentials() context?